React Formik Reset Country Field
the problem with my React components is that visually the country name does not reset when clicking on the "cancel" button.
import { useState, useRef } from 'react';
import { Form, Formik } from 'formik';
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
import { Button } from '@monorepo/kit-ui';
import { format, formatISO, parse } from 'date-fns';
import { IUpdateProfileForm } from '../../types';
import {
  useUpdateProfileFormSubmit,
  useUpdateProfileFormValidation,
} from '../../hooks';
import LastnameField from '../molecules/LastnameField';
import FirstnameField from '../molecules/FirstnameField';
import BirthdateField from '../molecules/BirthdateField';
import CountryField from '../molecules/CountryField';
import PhoneField from '../molecules/PhoneField';
import EmailField from '../molecules/EmailField';
import IsSubscribeNewsletterField from '../molecules/IsSubscribeNewsletterField';
import { useGetCurrentUser } from '../../../../hooks';
import { COUNTRIES } from '../../../../utils/countries';

const formatDate = (dateString) => {
  return format(new Date(dateString), 'yyyy-MM-dd');
};

const UpdateProfileForm = () => {
  const { currentUser, isCurrentUserLoading, isCurrentUserError } =
    useGetCurrentUser();
  const updateProfileFormValidation = useUpdateProfileFormValidation();
  const formikRef = useRef(null);
  const { submitUpdateProfileForm, isPending } = useUpdateProfileFormSubmit();
  const { t } = useTranslation();

  const [isEditing, setIsEditing] = useState(false);
  const [initialFormValues] = useState<IUpdateProfileForm>({
    lastname:
      !isCurrentUserLoading && !isCurrentUserError
        ? currentUser.lastname || ''
        : '',
    firstname:
      !isCurrentUserLoading && !isCurrentUserError
        ? currentUser.firstname || ''
        : '',
    dateOfBirth:
      !isCurrentUserLoading && !isCurrentUserError
        ? formatDate(currentUser.dateOfBirth) || ''
        : '',
    country:
      !isCurrentUserLoading && !isCurrentUserError
        ? currentUser.address.country || ''
        : '',
    phone:
      !isCurrentUserLoading && !isCurrentUserError
        ? currentUser.phone || ''
        : '',
    email:
      !isCurrentUserLoading && !isCurrentUserError
        ? currentUser.email || ''
        : '',
    isSubscribeNewsletter:
      !isCurrentUserLoading && !isCurrentUserError
        ? currentUser.isSubscribeNewsletter || false
        : false,
  });

  const onSubmit = async (values: IUpdateProfileForm) => {
    const formattedValues = {
      ...values,
      dateOfBirth: formatISO(
        parse(values.dateOfBirth, 'yyyy-MM-dd', new Date()),
      ),
      country:
        COUNTRIES.find((c) => c.title === values.country)?.value ||
        values.country,
    };

    submitUpdateProfileForm(formattedValues);
    setIsEditing(false);
  };

  const handleEditClick = () => {
    setIsEditing(true);
  };

  const handleCancelClick = () => {
    if (formikRef.current) {
      formikRef.current.resetForm();
    }
    setIsEditing(false);
  };

  return (
    <Formik
      innerRef={formikRef}
      enableReinitialize
      initialValues={initialFormValues}
      validationSchema={updateProfileFormValidation}
      onSubmit={onSubmit}
    >
      {(formik) => (
        <Form>
          <div className="grid md:grid-cols-2 gap-4 my-4">
            <label htmlFor="lastname" className="text-white">
              {t('auth.createAccount.input.lastName.placeholder')}
            </label>
            <LastnameField formik={formik} disabled={!isEditing} />

            <label htmlFor="firstname" className="text-white">
              {t('auth.createAccount.input.firstName.placeholder')}
            </label>
            <FirstnameField formik={formik} disabled={!isEditing} />

            <label htmlFor="birthdate" className="text-white">
              {t('auth.createAccount.input.dateOfBirth.placeholder')}
            </label>
            <BirthdateField formik={formik} disabled={!isEditing} />

            <label htmlFor="country" className="text-white">
              {t('auth.createAccount.input.country.placeholder')}
            </label>
            <CountryField formik={formik} disabled={!isEditing}/>

            <label htmlFor="phone" className="text-white">
              {t('auth.createAccount.input.phone.placeholder')}
            </label>
            <PhoneField formik={formik} disabled={!isEditing} />

            <label htmlFor="email" className="text-white">
              {t('auth.createAccount.input.email.placeholder')}
            </label>
            <EmailField formik={formik} disabled={true} />
          </div>

          {isEditing ? (
            <div className="flex space-x-4 mt-4">
              <Button
                variant="outline"
                className="px-6 py-3"
                type="button"
                onClick={handleCancelClick}
              >
                {t('home.navigation.form.cancel')}
              </Button>
              <Button
                className="px-6 py-3"
                type="submit"
                isLoading={isPending}
                disabled={!formik.dirty}
              >
                {t('home.navigation.form.save')}
              </Button>
            </div>
          ) : (
            <Button
              className="mt-4 px-6 py-3"
              type="button"
              onClick={handleEditClick}
            >
              {t('home.navigation.form.edit')}
            </Button>
          )}

          <div className="mt-4">
            <IsSubscribeNewsletterField formik={formik} disabled={!isEditing} />
          </div>
        </Form>
      )}
    </Formik>
  );
};

export default UpdateProfileForm;

import React, { useId } from 'react';
import { Field, FormikProps } from 'formik';
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
import { IUpdateProfileForm } from '../../types';
import CountrySelector from './CountrySelector';

interface CountryFieldProps {
  formik: FormikProps<IUpdateProfileForm>;
  disabled?: boolean;
}

const CountryField = ({ formik, disabled }: CountryFieldProps) => {
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  const { errors, touched } = formik;
  const id: string = useId();

  return (
    <Field
      component={CountrySelector}
      id={id}
      name="country"
      placeholder={t('auth.createAccount.input.country.placeholder')}
      required
      disabled={disabled}
      helperText={touched.country && errors.country}
      error={errors.country && touched.country}
      className="w-full"
    />
  );
};

export default CountryField;

import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { FlagIcon, FlagIconCode } from 'react-flag-kit';
import { FieldProps } from 'formik';
import { HelperText, InputProps, MenuItem, Select } from '@monorepo/kit-ui';
import { ICountry } from '../../../../types';
import { COUNTRIES } from '../../../../utils/countries';

const CountrySelector = ({ field, ...props }: InputProps & FieldProps) => {
  const [countries, setCountries] = useState<ICountry[]>(COUNTRIES);

  const handleChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const value = event.target.value.toLowerCase();
    const filteredCountries = COUNTRIES.filter((c) =>
      c.title.toLowerCase().includes(value),
    );
    const exactMatch = COUNTRIES.find((c) => c.title.toLowerCase() === value);
    setCountries(filteredCountries);
    if (exactMatch) {
      field.onChange({
        target: { value: exactMatch.value, name: field.name },
      } as React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>);
    } else {
      field.onChange(event);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="gap-1.5">
      <Select
        {...props}
        value={field.value}
        defaultValue={COUNTRIES.find((c) => c.value === field.value)?.title}
        name={field.name}
        onChange={handleChange}
        onBlur={field.onBlur}
        readOnly={false}
      >
        {countries.length === 0
          ? null
          : countries.map((country, index) => (
              <MenuItem key={index} value={country.title}>
                <div className="inline-flex gap-4 items-center">
                  <FlagIcon
                    code={country.value as FlagIconCode}
                    className="w-6 h-4"
                  />
                  {country.title}
                </div>
              </MenuItem>
            ))}
      </Select>
      {props.helperText && (
        <HelperText helperText={props.helperText} isError={props.error} />
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default CountrySelector;

EDIT : Here is the custom Select component:
import React, { PropsWithChildren, useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { ChevronDownIcon, ChevronUpIcon } from '@heroicons/react/20/solid';
import { InputText } from '../../atoms';
import { InputProps } from '../../../properties';

export const Select = ({
  children,
  type,
  onChange,
  readOnly = true,
  className,
  ...props
}: InputProps & PropsWithChildren) => {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  const [value, setValue] = useState(props.defaultValue || '');
  const selectRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

  const changeShow = (state: boolean) => {
    setShow(state);
  };

  const handleInputChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setValue(e.target.value);
    if (onChange) {
      onChange(e);
    }
  };

  const handleItemClick = (selectedLabel: string, selectedValue: string) => {
    setValue(selectedLabel || selectedValue);
    if (onChange) {
      onChange({
        target: { value: selectedValue, name: props.name },
      } as React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>);
    }
    setShow(false);
  };

  const handleDocumentClick = (e: MouseEvent) => {
    if (!selectRef.current?.contains(e.target as Node)) {
      setShow(false);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener('click', handleDocumentClick);

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener('click', handleDocumentClick);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div ref={selectRef} className={`relative inline-block ${className}`}>
      <div className="w-full" onClick={() => changeShow(!show)}>
        <InputText
          {...props}
          value={value}
          onChange={handleInputChange}
          className="cursor-pointer"
          readOnly={readOnly}
        />
        <span className="absolute right-2 top-2 pointer-events-none">
          {show ? (
            <ChevronUpIcon className="h-5 w-5 text-contrast-light" />
          ) : (
            <ChevronDownIcon className="h-5 w-5 text-contrast-light" />
          )}
        </span>
      </div>
      {show && children && (
        <div className="origin-top-left absolute left-0 pt-2 min-w-full z-50 animate-flip-down animate-ease-out">
          <ul
            className="flex flex-col p-2 gap-2 rounded-2xl
              shadow-lg bg-background-40 text-contrast-light max-h-[250px] overflow-y-scroll"
          >
            {React.Children.map(children, (child) => {
              if (
                props.value !== (child as React.ReactElement).props.value &&
                props.value !== (child as React.ReactElement).props.label
              ) {
                return React.cloneElement(child as React.ReactElement, {
                  onClick: handleItemClick,
                });
              }
            })}
          </ul>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

I would like that when clicking on "Cancel", the name and value of the field are reset with the initial values ​​of currentUser.address.country (for the country code) and therefore COUNTRIES.find((c) => c. value === currentUser.address.country)?.title for the name of the Country
What is the best way to do this?

We would need to knows what the imlementation of Select is. It's from @monorepo/kit-ui which I assume is internal to you. Is this based on some lib in itself or custom impl?

It's custom implementation. I have edit the post to add the code of this component.
